Null Issues in the Initialize Method of JavaFX Applications
I am working on a JavaFX application where I load course details from a previous screen (CourseDetailController) and display them in the CourseScreenController. The initialize method is supposed to set up the UI based on the selected course, including loading JSON data and dynamically populating the UI with sections and lessons.
The problem is that in the initialize method, the selectedCourse field is null or empty even though the setCourseDetails method sets its value before the scene is loaded.
Here is a code snippet from my CourseScreenController code:
public class CourseScreenController implements Basics {
    private String selectedCourse;
    private String courseName;

    // Setter method called when switching to this screen
    public void setCourseDetails(String imageUrl, String courseName, String instructor, String duration, String description, String language) {
        this.courseName = courseName;
        selectedJSON(courseName);  // Determine the course JSON path
    }

    public void selectedJSON(String courseName) {
        if (courseName.equals("Java Programming")) {
            selectedCourse = "src/main/data/courses_data/java.json";
        } else if (courseName.equals("Python Programming")) {
            selectedCourse = "src/main/data/courses_data/python.json";
        } else if (courseName.equals("C++ Programming")) {
            selectedCourse = "src/main/data/courses_data/cpp.json";
        } else if (courseName.equals("WEB Programming")) {
            selectedCourse = "src/main/data/courses_data/web.json";
        } else {
            System.out.println("Course not found!");
            selectedCourse = null;
        }
    }

    @FXML
    public void initialize() {
        System.out.println("Selected course: " + selectedCourse);
        if (selectedCourse == null || selectedCourse.isEmpty()) {
            System.err.println("Course path is not set. Defaulting to Python course.");
            selectedCourse = "src/main/data/courses_data/python.json";
        }

        // Further logic to load sections and populate UI
    }
}


Despite calling setCourseDetails before the initialize method, selectedCourse is still null in initialize. I suspect this is because the initialize method executes before setCourseDetails.
Debugged and verified that setCourseDetails is called and sets the value correctly.
Checked the execution order and realized initialize runs first.
1- How can I ensure selectedCourse is correctly set before initialize processes the logic?
2- Is there a better way to pass data between controllers in JavaFX to avoid such issues?
Since I’m new to Java, any explanation or resources for understanding this better would be greatly appreciated.

Do you manually call initialize()? FXMLLoader.load() automatically calls it, so make sure you call your setter before loading the scene.

Maybe you forgot to add the @FXML annotation for member variables selectedCourse and courseName in class CourseScreenController?

Create and post a [mre]. You say you call setCourseDetails(…) before the initialize() method is invoked, but nothing in your post shows that to be true (and to do that takes significant effort).
